# Demand Function in monopoly

Tags: microeconomics, monopoly, demand, nonexpert

I am studying monopoly and I see that most exercises use inverse demand. why use the inverse demand function instead of the demand function?

Comment: See my reply here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/41336/11590 and also see here https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/140/why-is-price-on-the-vertical-axis-and-quantity-on-the-horizontal-axis

Comment: @Bayesian so since the monopolist has power over the market price, then
its marginal benefit is a function of its quantity and not the price as perfect competition. Is this it?